# Unable to send additional data through $.post()

Tags: jquery, cookies, http-post, postback

Using $.post(), I am trying to send over the value of a `$.cookie('pear')` to my PHP form where it will do some stuff with it. But the problem is, the PHP form doesn't seem to be able to receive the value of `$.cookie('pear')`.

*Just to be clear, `$.cookie('pear')` definitely has a value. I did an `alert($.cookie('pear'))` to double-check and it definitely shows the value of `$.cookie('pear')`.*

Check out my code below. Appreciate help in pointing out on what's wrong with it. Maybe there's something wrong with my implementation of $.post()?

**jQuery**

```
submit_fruit.on({

    click: function () {

      $('#market').click();

      var pears = $.cookie('pears')

      alert(pears) // this works. it alert the value of the cookie 'pears'

      $.post('fruitsubmission.php', { pears: pears }, function(data) {

    }); // but this troublesome piece of $.post() doesn't seem to send 'pears' over to the PHP form.

}

});
```

**PHP**

```
$fruit = $_POST['pears'];

echo $fruit;

-- some mySQL data submissions stuff here --
```

But I can't get the value 'pears' that was sent over from the $.post() call.

**Error report**

```
Notice: Undefined index: pears in ******* on line 10
```

Comment: Why are you using the `#` character in `$.post('#fruitsubmission.php', ...`? Using it like this has the effect of posting to the page that originated the request. Is that what you intended?

Comment: sorry, that was an oversight of mine. I meant it without the hashtag. I still get the same error report though.

Comment: If you set `var pears = "this is a test";` do you get the same error?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the `PHP Notice: Undefined index` when I set `pears` as an empty array or empty object:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // var pears = {};
    var pears = new Array();
    $.post('fruitsubmission.php', { pears: pears }, function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
});
</script>
```

When I set it to something like `var pears = "this is a test";`, it works as expected, so maybe the error you're getting is being caused by some other part of your script.

Try to isolate this error on your environment, you can start with the script above, and add the other elements as you go.